# Custom metrics on Cloudera Hadoop Distribution

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, dashboard, metrics, operations

I'm using Cloudera - moslty starting oozie and yarn jobs. I would like to emit certain metrics and print them as a dashboard - connect data from multiple oozie jobs on one graph.

I see that there is a way to collect metrics from multiple standard components - like HBase, Hive etc (https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cm_metrics.html). Can I use this mechanism to add my custom metrics and dashboards?

Comment: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cm_metrics_oozie_server.html#concept_ywj_amn_yk

Comment: It's more about my custom metrics. Something that I would like to emit from my Java code.

Comment: I see... I don't think Cloudera metrics are open source like that for you to just integrate them in your code. I've seen most companies use Solr or Grafana for collecting data from their code